# $V^{**}\simeq V$ as $\mathbb{K}[G]$ modules

Tags: representation-theory

Let $G$ be a group and $V$ over $\mathbb{K}$ be a finite dimensional representation of $G$. Show that  $V^{**}\simeq V$ as $\mathbb{K}[G]$ modules. Prove that if $V$ is a irreducible representation then  $V^{*}$ is a irreducible representation. I tried to show that $w\mapsto ev_w  $, where   $ev_w(f)= f(w)$, $\forall f\in Hom(V,\mathbb{K})$, it is the right isomorphism, but I didn't succeed.

Comment: What went wrong? Remember how the action of $G$ on a dual space is defined.

Comment: @Tobias Kildetoft I have to show  that $f(g\cdot w) = g\cdot f (w), \forall f\in Hom (V, K), \forall  g\in G, \forall w\in V$.

Comment: No, that is not what you need to show, since that is not how the group acts.

Comment: I think you need to write up what the action of $G$ on $V^*$ is in terms of the action on $V$ before you go any further.

Comment: $ (g\cdot f)(w) = f(g^{-1}\cdot w)$

Comment: Great. So the action of $G$ on the double dual becomes?

Comment: Great! I understand! Thank you! And the second assertion?

Comment: Show that a the dual of a submodule is a submodule of the dual (then apply the first part).

Comment: Actually, that was not right. You should show that the dual of a submodule is a quotient of the dual.

Comment: Why the dual of the submodule isn't a submodule of the dual?

Comment: It turns out to be when the module is completely reducible, but since none of the statements here require that, it was not necessary to go into (and it is in fact easier to show that correct statement I made than the "nicer" one).

Comment: The morphism from $V^{*}$ to $W^{*}$, where $W$ is a submodule of $V$, is the restriction?

Comment: Yes, exactly (in general, any map between vector spaces induces a map in the opposite direction between their duals)

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft  One   more   question.... I   know  that $W^{*}$  is    is   isomorphic   to  a   quotient  of $V^{*}$.   Why   this   remark  solves  my   problem?

Comment: This shows that if $V$ is reducible then so is its dual. But this becomes an iff by the first part by dualizing again.

Comment: $V^{*}$ is irreducible if and only if it is simple as $K[G]$ module. Who is the submodule of $V^{*}$?  The fact that $V$ is finite dimensional over $K$ is superfluous?

Comment: The non-trivial submodule of the dual is the kernel of the projection to the non-trivial quotient you got from the rep itself.